# How to reduce the character as small as possible for the assigned function in Python

Tags: python, simplify

For Python,

```
def fun1(name, ext):
    if ext == '' :
        fname = name + '$'
    else:
        fname = name + ext
    return fname
```

I have to make fun2 as short as possible with less than 25 characters that work exactly the same as fun1.

So far, I made

```
def fun2(name, ext):
    if ext == '':
        ext = '$'
    return name + ext
```

but it still exceeds 25 characters.
Is there any possible way to accomplish this without any external tools or extensions?

Comment: `def f(n,e):return n+e or"$"` or `f=lambda n,e:n+e or"$"`

Comment: How about using a mix of Devakamar's idea and changing the variable names?

    def fun1(n, e):
        return n+'$' if e=='' else n+e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fun2(name, ext):
    e = ext or '$'
    return name + e
```

Answer (score 1):

Using python's ternary operator

```
def fun1(name, ext):
    return name+'$' if ext=='' else name+ext
```

See more: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-operator-in-python/

Comment: this still exceeds 25 characters but thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the shortest way without `ext==''`

```py
def fun2(name, ext):
    return name+ext if ext else name+"$"
```